# How to compute moving dot products of time series with exponentially decaying weights?

Tags: orthogonal-signals, orthornormal

I have to apply the Gram Schmidt algorithm on discrete time series to make them orthogonal and normalized.

This implies that I compute dot products, but it is of course not applicable for very long time series. I assume that this is something done frequently in signal processing but I failed to find any useful help with google.

A solution could be to use sliding windows but it is too memory expensive.

Could it be possible to use the equivalent of the mobile mean with exponentially decaying mean ? The recurrence is very simple.

$$m_t = m_{t-1} + \alpha(x_t - m_{t-1})$$

When $\alpha = 1/n$ with n starting at 1, we have the mean $m = \sum x_t / n$.

I tried it with the dot product, but it doesn't work. I'm not very good at math. Some help would be welcome.

---

**EDIT**

The recurrence to compute the mean above is called the Exponential Mean Weight Average (EMWA). [thank you GPT]

It can indeed be used to compute the normalization of a time series.

$$emwa : m_t = m_{t-1} + \alpha(x_t - m_{t-1})$$

The time series normalization is computed with

$$v_i = \frac {u_i} {\sqrt {emwa(u_iu_i)}}$$

The dot product of a time series must be computed with a normalized dot product.

$$d_i = \frac {emwa(a_ib_i)} {\sqrt{emwa(a_ia_i)emwa(b_ib_i)}}$$

In the following graphic, $u$ is the time series values, $v$ the normalized values, and $d(v,v)$ the normalized dot product of v which yields 1 as it should. $\alpha = .03$ and $u$ are 100 values in the range 0.1 to 4.

[image: Test of normalization and its dot product]

**EDIT2**

While nice looking, it is unfortunately incorrect.

Comment: You seem to have an answer.  Your $m_t$ equation is a ***recursive*** method of computing this exponentially-weighted mean.  But the result is not $$ \sum\limits_{t=1}^n \frac{x_t}{n} $$  That's an equally-weighted mean.  This is an IIR.  The dot-product is an FIR and cannot be perfectly equivalent for any finite length $n$.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson thanks for helping. I checked if I could use this recursion applied to dot products to also normalize the time series. I assumed that the time series would be normalized when the dot product with itself would be 1. Unfortunately, the result is quite different from 1. I thus assume I make a mistake somewhere.

Comment: $$m_t = m_{t-1} + \alpha(x_t - m_{t-1}) = (1-\alpha)m_{t-1} + \alpha x_t$$

The DC gain of that filter is 1 or zero dB.  It is properly scaled to give you the mean.  If $x_t = x_0 =$ constant, then the output is $m_t = x_0$ without additional scaling.  You need: $$ 0 < \alpha \ll 1 $$ to make this recursive version work well.

Comment: Also to compare to FIR (but it ain't really *"F"*) is equivalent to: $$ m_t = \alpha \sum\limits_{i=0}^{\infty} x_{t-i} \, (1-\alpha)^{-i} $$  That's sorta a dot product but the vectors are infinitely long.